# Appending more images to install.wim. Would it be applied as well?

Tags: installation, setup, dism, wim

I'm appending an image of another drive, D:, to install.wim (an install.wim that already contains a slightly customized Windows). The additional image of D: is of course at index 2. When I run the OS installation setup, would the setup also deploy the second image or not? How could I get it do so? Would there be potential problems of mis-labeling which is volume D: to be applied to?

Comment: So only image index 1 gets applied? That's Microsoft for you not thinking of this ahead. They never appreciated bleeding edges.

Comment: Know how to write a script at the end of the setup that applies the second image?

Comment: Oh, I know the commands, just not how to prepare it in a script that would execute near the end of the setup.

Comment: My profile name is intentionally vague with regards to my gender or any specifics about me as a person as that information specifically with regards to my gender is completely and utterly irrelevant to anything on this website or any other website.